# the correct term for the killing of an entire species

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

in research of this word, I don't believe there is an exact word. But I'm looking for a word with the suffix "-cide" at the end. If we go by other words in a similar formate like genocide (Geno being greek for race) then it's possible it would be: eídoscide (Eidos being greek for species). The correct term has to cover all of any one species, but only the one species. (so no, omnicide or mundicide)

Comment: The Greek for ‘race’ is _genos_, not _geno_; that’s it compounding form. Similarly, ‘species’ is _eidos_ (though I’m sure there are better words; this one basically just means ‘appearance’), whose compounding form is _eido-_, so you’d have _eidocide_. Doesn’t seem to exist, though.

Answer (score 3):

[Speciocide](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/speciocide) is "the elimination of an entire species" [Collins English Dictionary].

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to supplement user282290's answer by noting some alternative forms that are also in use:

- **specicide**. In 2003, the New York Times published the opinion piece "[A Bug's Death](http://www.nytimes.com/2003/09/25/opinion/a-bug-s-death.html)", by Olivia Judson, which uses the term "specicide" and defines it as "the deliberate extinction of an entire species". (The phrase "deliberate extinction" also works as a less neologistic term for this.)
- **[speciescide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speciescide)** (mentioned on Wiktionary). (perhaps compare "speciesism"/"speciesist" for the first part, and "[viruscide](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/viruscide)" for the second part) and
- **speciecide** (also mentioned at the Wiktionary link)
- **speciesicide**. Seems to have been used by some people, including in at least one [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=3VkoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&lpg=PT99&dq=%22speciesicide%22&source=bl&ots=H3nJYbZvZo&sig=chfHK_rRYvUttNh1siCTBlZAE9E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2marDrOPZAhVCba0KHYkoBOIQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=%22speciesicide%22&f=false).